# A websocket's ReceiveAsync method does not await the entire message

Tags: c#, websocket, async-await

I am receiving JSON through a websocket. At least: I am partially. Using an online websocket service I receive the full JSON response (all the HTML markup is ignored). When I look at the JSON that I receive in my console I can see the HTML markup (viewing it with the HTML viewer during debugging removes the HTML) but it ends abruptly (incomplete data).

My buffer has plenty of space and I am using async-await to (supposedly) wait for the entire response to come in before continuing.

```
private async Task Receive()
{
  var buffer = new byte[4096 * 20];

  while (_socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
  {
      var response = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

      if (response.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
      {
          await
              _socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Close response received",
                  CancellationToken.None);
      }
      else
      {
          var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
          var a = buffer[1000];
          var b = buffer[10000];
          var c = buffer[50000];
          var d = buffer[81000];
          Console.WriteLine(result);
          var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result, _requestParameters.ResponseDataType);

          OnSocketReceive.Invoke(this, new SocketEventArgs {Response = responseObject });
          buffer = new byte[4096 * 20];
      }
  }
}
```

Things to note: The buffer is perfectly big enough and `b`, `c` and `d` are never filled. I should also note that this only happens for the `1-questions-newest-tag-java` request, `155-questions-active` works perfectly fine.

After doing some digging I have found that `response.CloseStatus` and `response.CloseStatusDescription` are always `null`, `response.Count` is always `1396` (copy-pasting the result in Word does show that there are always 1396 characters) and `response.EndOfMessage` is `false`.

Digging through [some source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/ClientWebSocket.cs#6fd04c76fe32d754) I have found that the [`DefaultReceiveBufferSize`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketHelpers.cs#285b8b64a4da6851) is `16 * 1024` (big enough) and the `WebSocketGetDefaultKeepAliveInterval()` refers to [an external implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketProtocolComponent.cs#3039008acf8baff7) (but the debugger shows `00:00:30`).

It is not a matter of timeout since the debugger halts at the same moment the online service receives its response.

Why is my method continuing to execute when the socket has not yet received all data?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I don't think you're always supposed to receive a complete `WebSocket` message at once. The server may be sending the message in chunks (that'd correspond to calling `SendAsync` with `endOfMessage: false`).

So, do `await _socket.ReceiveAsync()` in a loop and accumulate the received chunks, until `WebSocketReceiveResult.EndOfMessage` is `true` or an error has occured.

On a side note, you probably should be using `WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer` instead of `new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer)`.

Comment: Using a loop to construct the message worked indeed. So `ReceiveAsync` considers itself "awaited" once the entire chunk has been sent instead of when the entire message has been received, thanks for clarifying that. As to your sidenote: what are the benefits of doing it that way?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, regarding `CreateClientBuffer` - it's just my gut feeling, because the API is there. Check for yourself [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocket.cs#eabc0b45ff3ecd2c) in the Reference Source, whether this is the case.

Comment: Just to add to the above, even if the server does send in one chunk (ie endOfMessage = true), I found that the ClientWebSocket can receive a partial message, in particular if it's a large message that's over the web socket's internal receive buffer size (which seems to be about 16k by default). So using a loop to build up the full message from chunks as you recommend does seem to be necessary.

Comment: @Noseratio This seems like it might be an internal method or something - looking at Reference Source, it doesn't seem to be that helpful if you want an explicitly-sized buffer.

Comment: @rookie1024, which one? [`WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.createclientbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx) certainly isn't.

Comment: @Noseratio I'm just not sure how you'd use something like that without knowing what it does behind-the-scenes, since it makes a buffer to use for both sending and receiving plus some kind of overhead.

Comment: CreateClientBuffer should probably be not used. It seems to be called internally. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723517/4394435

Comment: adding to Saxon Druce comment: it is not just when some internal buffer is too small. When the buffer called with ReceiveAsync(buffer, default), is too small, it will automatically split the message into multiple parts. e.g. 100 bytes message, 10 bytes buffer. Then you have to call ReceiveAsync(buffer, default) 10 times until you received the full 100 bytes message and EndOfMessage = true. With a 100 instead of 10 bytes buffer a single ReceiveAsync() is enough in that case.

Comment: And it seems to randomly happen too, even when server is not chunking and c# programm is restarted. It happens after arbitary total received bytes/messages. e.g. sometimes after 10000 bytes, sometimes after 50000 bytes etc. even when the message size is always just 100 bytes.

Answer (score 46):

Just to complete @Noseratio response, the code would be something like this:

```
ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[8192]);

WebSocketReceiveResult result= null;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     do
     {
         result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
         ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
     }
     while (!result.EndOfMessage);

     ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

     if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
     {
          using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
          {
               // do stuff
          }
     }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up. Is there an advantage of using a stream instead of a temporary array as in my approach, or are they equal alternatives?

Comment: A MemoryStream is a Byte[] internally, probably there is little to none technical benefit, but I always use them for convenience as long I am expecting concrete messages.

Comment: A note: one should consider creating received data size threshold as a remote side could cause memory overflow. To handle this one would add if (MaxReceivedMessageSize <= ms.Length) { ... } inside the loop.

Answer (score 8):

```
// Read the bytes from the web socket and accumulate all into a list.
var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;
var allBytes = new List<byte>();

do
{
    result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    {
        allBytes.Add(buffer.Array[i]);
    }
}
while (!result.EndOfMessage);

// Optional step to convert to a string (UTF-8 encoding).
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(allBytes.ToArray(), 0, allBytes.Count);
```

Answer (score 5):

Following Noseratio's answer I have implemented a temporary buffer that will construct the data of the entire message.

```
var temporaryBuffer = new byte[BufferSize];
var buffer = new byte[BufferSize * 20];
int offset = 0;
WebSocketReceiveResult response;

while (true)
{
    response = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(
                         new ArraySegment<byte>(temporaryBuffer), 
                         CancellationToken.None);
    temporaryBuffer.CopyTo(buffer, offset);
    offset += response.Count;
    temporaryBuffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    if (response.EndOfMessage)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Full implementation [here](https://github.com/Vannevelj/StackSockets/blob/master/StackSockets/Library/StackSocket.cs)

Comment: @vtortola's answers is safe because he writes (copies) things in a `MemoryStream` that will grow as needed. In your answer the maximum size is `BufferSize * 20`, so you'll get some exception if you go beyond. If you know you'll never go over `BufferSize * 20`, you should always create an `ArraySegment` around `buffer` and just specify where it starts. That way you avoid the `CopyTo` and the `new byte[BufferSize]` in each step of your `while`.

Comment: What's the reason for the `* 20`, rather than just having `BufferSize` be larger to begin with?

Comment: Also, I looked at the full implementation and it looks like it's designed to connect, send, receive, and disconnect, but I thought that one of the key usages of sockets is to remain connected, so would that implementation have performance implications?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
try
{
    WebSocketReceiveResult result;
    string receivedMessage = "";
    var message = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[4096]);
    do
    {
        result = await WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(message, DisconectToken);
        if (result.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            break;
        var messageBytes = message.Skip(message.Offset).Take(result.Count).ToArray();
        receivedMessage += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes);                    
    }
    while (!result.EndOfMessage);
    if (receivedMessage != "{}" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(receivedMessage))
    {
        ResolveWebSocketResponse.Invoke(receivedMessage, Connection);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", receivedMessage);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var mes = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this approach might break when an UTF-8 sequence crosses a message boundary - AFAICS, the UTF8.GetString() will fail with an decoder error as it only has the partial sequence.

Comment: Addition: RFC 6455 explicitly says: "Note that a particular text frame might include a partial UTF-8 sequence". And both sides may not rely on a specific fragmentation, as intermediates may refragment the messages.