# Buffer filled by nulls. Websockets .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, websocket, asp.net-core

I built application like live chat in .net core and angular.
Everything works fine, but, the buffer where received messages are stored, have null bytes after content.

My buffer have 1024 bytes size.
But if the message has e.g. 60 bytes, the rest is filled by nulls.

Should I rewrite received message to new buffer(with appropriate size), and then send further just this new one buffer? (This method I am using now)

Below is my receive method:

```
private async Task Recive(WebSocket socket, Action<WebSocketReceiveResult, byte[]> handle) //original 
{   
    while(socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync
        (
            buffer: new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer),
            cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None
        );

        handle(result, buffer);
    }
}
```

Handle is a function which is called, after app receives data.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer is just that, a buffer, and thus it won't automatically resize if it's larger than the actual data. You can try:

```
private async Task Receive(WebSocket socket, Action<WebSocketReceiveResult, byte[]> handle) //original 
{   
    while(socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
        var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync
        (
            buffer: buffer,
            cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None
        );

        var resized = new byte[buffer.Count];
        Array.Copy(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, resized, 0, buffer.Count);
        handle(result, resized);
    }
}
```

Note that your code won't work if you receive a message that's larger than 1024 bytes. You can check the proper way to retrieve the full content of the message (and how to process it further) here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23784968/2698119