# WebSocket.CreateServerBuffer vs. WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

I've been able to implement a server-side Web Socket solution using ASP.NET Core, however, I can't find any good documentation on the difference between [`WebSocket.CreateServerBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.createserverbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.createclientbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx), and when to use either.

Can anyone shed some light on when/how to use them?

Comment: They both appear to be send buffers.  I notice server buffers have a hard coded minimum.  Maybe because a server needs to be more careful, they override the size specified with this minimum of 16 for server buffers: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/ed99fbb7295acc3c.html  I'm speculating, for security you should use CreateServerBuffer if you are in the context of a server.

Comment: Interesting. I also noticed that the constructor for `CreateClientBuffer` also requires a `sendBufferSize`, but am having a hard time joining the dots. Thanks for above info.

Comment: If you click on a name of the method in code, it'll give you results where it is called from.  So I can work backwards and see where CreateServerBuffer is called from.  I only found one place and it works back to https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/f92ea7d9f3137403.html where it seems to be for HttpListenerContext

Comment: CreateClientbuffer is used in a ServiceModel for receiving a response, and in ClientWebSocket class(indirectly through several calls)

Comment: @AaronLS, that's really useful, but these are public methods. I would've expected more around when and where to use each from their documentation :( Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Usage

`WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer` is primarily called with the `ConnectAsync()` method an instance of `ClientWebSocket`.

```
ClientWebSocket clientWS = new ClientWebSocket();
await clientWS.ConnectAsync(...);  // will create the client buffer
```

### CreateClientBuffer vs CreateServerBuffer

The only difference, essentially is that `CreateClientBuffer` allows you to define the `sendBufferSize`, whereas the `CreateServerBuffer` will not (and will default the `sendBufferSize` to 16).

> It appears that they both exist mainly to serve the purpose of separating the concerns between a `ClientWebSocket` and a `ServerWebSocket` which are both just instances derived from the abstract class `WebSocket`.

---

#### Additional Detail

Take look at the [WebSocket.cs at Microsoft Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocket.cs,eabc0b45ff3ecd2c) to see the implementation:

```
// [WebSocketBuffer.cs] const int MinSendBufferSize = 16;

public static ArraySegment<byte> CreateClientBuffer(int receiveBufferSize, int sendBufferSize)
{
    WebSocketHelpers.ValidateBufferSizes(receiveBufferSize, sendBufferSize);

    return WebSocketBuffer.CreateInternalBufferArraySegment(receiveBufferSize, sendBufferSize, false);
}

public static ArraySegment<byte> CreateServerBuffer(int receiveBufferSize)
{
    WebSocketHelpers.ValidateBufferSizes(receiveBufferSize, WebSocketBuffer.MinSendBufferSize);

    return WebSocketBuffer.CreateInternalBufferArraySegment(receiveBufferSize, WebSocketBuffer.MinSendBufferSize, true);
}
```

They both create a new instance of a `WebSocketBuffer` but pass different minimum `sendBufferSize` values

The `CreateServerBuffer()` method will always use the `MinSendBufferSize = 16`. Otherwise, the `CreateClientBuffer()` uses the value passed.

Comment: Good summary of above comments. Thanks.