# Couldn't fetch response more than 4096 byte in Chat (Socket)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, websocket

I am working on Chat using [ClientWebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=netframework-4.8) in C#. I can receive message but in 2 packets of 4096 byte. How to get the whole in one hit?

**Code**

```
 public async void ConnectToServerAsync()
{
ClientWebSocket client = new ClientWebSocket();

    await client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://local123:ws"), CancellationToken.None);
            UpdateClientState();
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                Refresh();

                    WebSocketReceiveResult result;

                    var buf = new byte[8192];

                    var message = new ArraySegment<byte>(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                        result = await client.ReceiveAsync(message, CancellationToken.None);
                        //var messageBytes = message.Skip(message.Offset).Take(result.Count).ToArray();
                        string serialisedMessae = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf,0,result.Count);

                        try
                        {
                            var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChatModel>>(serialisedMessae);
                            Debug.WriteLine(msg.Count);
                            if (Chatlist.Count != msg.Count)
                            {
                                Chatlist.Clear();
                                foreach (var chatmsg in msg)
                                {
                                    var details = new ChatModel()
                                    {
                                        Message = chatmsg.Message,
                                        MessageFrom = chatmsg.MessageFrom,
                                        MessageTo = chatmsg.MessageTo,
                                        RoomId = chatmsg.RoomId,

                                    };
                                    Chatlist.Insert(0, details);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Invalide message format. {ex.Message}");
                        }


                }

            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
            void UpdateClientState()
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsConnected));
                sendMessageCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
                Console.WriteLine($"Websocket state {client.State}");
            }
        }
```

When I deserialize the response. I could get one partial json in one packet and rest in another packet. How to get the whole json at once ?

Comment: `8192`. You want me to put like this `var buf = new byte[4096 * 2];` ?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773407/a-websockets-receiveasync-method-does-not-await-the-entire-message ?

Comment: You will need `DeserializeObject` **outside** of the `do` loop.

Comment: Read the duplicate. You aren't using `EndOfMessage` for example.

Comment: I could the response the two packets. One half in one and another half in another